# loading/require luarocks installed using --local arguement

Tags: lua, torch, luarocks

I am trying to load a lua module after installing it as  'luarocks install --local tds'.

But I am not able to load the package when I do require 'tds'. Is there a path which I would have to add to search path to load this module?

Comment: Do you get an error? If `tds`is nil, then do `local tds = require 'tds'`.

Comment: The `luarocks path` command will provide the `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` variable definitions, or you can set these using `package.path` and `package.cpath` in Lua.

Comment: Wild guess: Try `require "luarocks.loader"` first. That fixed a related problem for me. (Not sure if this works, and can't test right now. If it does work, I can turn this comment into a real answer.)

Comment: if you encounter the problem and you want help you should describe the problem (including any unexpected behavior and error messages) instead of just saying that you are unable to do something.

Comment: local tds = require 'tds' made it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `tds` is nil after `require 'tds'`,
then do `local tds = require 'tds'`.